# How does the value of K determine number of local optima in NK model?

Tags: evolution, theoretical-biology

**BACKGROUND**

The **NK** model of fitness landscape considers **N** states which can interact with **K** other states. For example **N** is the total number of genes in a haploid genome and **K** is the number of other genes that each gene may interact with.

In [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519389800190) article Kaufman says:

> The fully connected NK model yields a completely random fitness
>   landscape. For **K = N - 1**, the fitness contribution of each site
>   depends on all of the other sites in the sequence and therefore
>   altering any site from one to the other value, 0-1, alters the fitness
>   contribution of each site to a new random value. Thus the fitness of
>   any 1-mutant neighboring sequence is completely random with respect to
>   the initial sequence. The landscape is fully random. As was shown in
>   Kauffman & Levin (1987), Weinberger (1988), and Macken & Pereison
>   (1989), such random landscapes have very many local optima, on
>   average, **2<sup>N</sup>/(N +1)**.

I did not read the references mentioned in the text but I read the related section in Kaufman's book: *Origins of Order: Self-Organization and Selection in Evolution*.

In the book he says that the fitness of a genotype can be ordered and given ranks; the probability that a genotype is fitter than its neighbours (local optima) is same as its probability of ranking higher than its **N** neighbours. So this probability:

$$P_m=\frac{1}{N+1}$$

and if each gene can have only two states lets say *on* or *off* then the expected number of optima with respect to one-mutants (i.e. the difference between a gene and its neighbour is just one mutation) would be:

$$M_1=\frac{2^N}{N+1}$$

What I don't understand is the role of **K** in this expression. This reason should be valid for any number of **K** (See the quote above). Even in the book this explanation is given in the case where **K** is maximum i.e. **N-1**. I can understand that **K** can affect the ruggedness of the landscape but can anyone explain how **K** affects the number of optima? (*or are they just two separate statements written together, which is confusing me*)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the opposite extreme, $K=0$, so that each site has an independent effect on fitness. Without loss of generality, we can say that at each locus $n$, the $1$ allele confers an advantage $s_n$ over the $0$ allele. Then there is just one local optimum, the global optimum, at $\vec{1}$, so $M_1=1$ (and $P_m=2^{-N}$).

The key difference is that in the $K=0$ case each fitness comparison of a focal genotype with a neighbor is independent of the rest: the fact that mutating the first gene decreases fitness, for instance, doesn't make it any more likely that mutating the second gene will decrease fitness. For any $K$, it is necessarily true that the focal genotype has a probability $1/(N+1)$ of being fitter than all of a set of $N$ other *randomly chosen* genotypes, but we're interested in comparing it to its neighbors, which are not a random selection, and are only equivalent to a random selection when $K=N-1$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Sorry I for the late response. Was out of town and didn't check. So except for the `N=0` case, it is not straightforward to predict the number of optima from the value of `K` or is it monotonously increasing?

Comment: No need to apologize! I think that it's monotonously increasing, but I'm not sure if it's been proved in general. There are a couple of papers by Vlada Limic in Ann. Prob. (2003 with Rick Durrett, 2004 with Robin Pemantle) that look at related questions.